# Loading JSON dynamically with $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

So I'm taking my first steps with Angular. In the slightly simplified code below I'm trying to load a JSON file that matches the URL (eg. ex1.html loads ex1.json).

```
var exerciseApp = angular.module('exerciseApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);

exerciseApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
   $stateProvider
    .state('exercise', {
      url: '/{exId:ex[0-9]{1,2}}',
      controller  : 'loadContent'
    });
});

exerciseApp.controller('loadContent', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $http.get('/content/'+$stateParams.exId+'.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.excontent=data;
    })
});
```

It works fine if the $http.get just says ('/content/ex1.json').

As it is, the app does seem to be seeing the ex.json file (a file not found error isn't returned if there is an ex1.json file in the content folder).

I'm sure I've seen something like this working elsewhere. What am I doing wrong?

**Solved: Realised my mistake. I hadn't wrapped the values I wanted to display in the view template within `ui-view`. The JSON was loading but there was nowhere in the view to show it.**

Comment: Have you looked at the get request using fiddler or used your web browser's debugging tools to examine the value of $stateParams.exId? You will likely find the answer there.

Comment: What is the actual value you're typing into the browser bar?

Comment: The value I type in the browser bar would be something like /ex1, /ex2. If I log $stateParams.exID in the console I see 'ex1' and 'ex2' appearing as I'd expected. If there's a matching JSON file that's it. If there isn't, it'll say file not found.  Looking more closely at the 'Get' request, it's definitely finding and getting the file -- the issue seems to be it's not displaying in the view.

Comment: _Solved:_ Realised my mistake. I hadn't set-up `ui-view` in the template to display the content. The JSON was loading but there was nowhere in the view to show it.